# Interface is Not assignable to Type NgIterable in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, typescript

I want to edit the record in my Application so I have to bring the previous record of the employee i'm beginner tho need assist i have shared my code down below help me to fix the issue

I have used the Interface and Services My services are working but implementing the interface is not working says that i have to use the array declaration to fetch the record

My emp-update-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IEmp } from '../iemp';
import { ActivatedRoute,Router } from '@angular/router';
import { EmpServiceService } from '../emp-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-update',
  templateUrl: './employee-update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-update.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
emp:IEmp = {empid:0,name:'',salary:0,deptid:0,email:'',Manager:''};

id:number=0;

  constructor(private empservice:EmpServiceService,private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.emp.empid = this.emp.empid;
    const tid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.id  = Number(tid);
    this.getEmp(this.id);
  }

  getEmp(id:number){
    this.empservice.getEmp(id).subscribe((data:IEmp)=>{this.emp=data;console.log(data);});
  }

  UpdateEmp(emp:IEmp){
    this.emp=emp;
    this.empservice.updateEmp(this.emp).subscribe(()=>{
      alert("Recorded Edited");
  this.router.navigate(['/list']);
  });
  }

}
```

My interface

```
export interface IEmp {
    empid:number;
    name:string;
    salary:number;
    deptid:number;
    email:string;
    Manager:string;
}
```

my Html part

```
<div class="container" style="position: relative;top: 80px;">
<h1>Update Employee Form</h1>
<form (ngSubmit)='UpdateEmp(emp)' #empForm='ngForm'>    
    <div> 
        <label for='empid'>Employee Employee ID</label>        
        <input type='number' id='id' name='id' placeholder="Enter Employee Id" [(ngModel)]='emp.empid' readonly  #id=ngModel />        
    </div>
    <div> 
        <label for='name'>Enter Employee Name:</label>        
        <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder="Enter Employee Name" [(ngModel)]='emp.name' required  #name=ngModel />        
    </div>
    <div> 
        <label for='salary'>Enter Employee salary:</label>        
        <input type='number' id='salary' name='salary' placeholder="Enter Employee salary" [(ngModel)]='emp.salary' required    #name=ngModel />        
        
    </div>


    <div>        
        <label for='deptid'>Enter Employee Dept:</label>        
        <input type='number' id='deptid' name='deptid' placeholder="Enter Employee deptid" [(ngModel)]='emp.deptid' required    #name=ngModel />        
    </div>  

    <div>        
        <label for='email'>Enter Employee email:</label>        
        <input type='text' id='email' name='email' placeholder="Enter Employee dept" [(ngModel)]='emp.email' required    #name=ngModel />        
        
    </div> 


    <div>        
        <label for='Manager'>Enter Employee manager:</label>        
        <input type='text' id='Manager' name='Manager' placeholder="Enter Employee Manager" [(ngModel)]='emp.Manager' required    #name=ngModel />        
       
    </div>

       
    <div>        
        <input type="submit" value='Save'  />    
    </div>
</form>

<div *ngFor="let em of emp">
    {{em.empid}}

</div>
```

My Error

```
src/app/employee-update/employee-update.component.html:43:21 - error TS2322: Type 'IEmp' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'.

43 <div *ngFor="let em of emp">
                       ~~

  src/app/employee-update/employee-update.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './employee-update.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component EmployeeUpdateComponent.
```

Comment: your'e trying to iterate over emp object which isn't iterable.

Comment: what should i do I need to display the existing records

Comment: post your whole code so i can see the *ngFor line (should be line 43 according to the error)

Comment: I have posted everything here... what should i post rather than this !!!!

Comment: replace your ngFor with *ngIf="emp?.empId"

Comment: Actually my problem is i want to edit the employee record when they click edit it will redirect to next page where all the record of the employee should display here i wanted to edit there record. the request and response are working i can see them in the console but i want to display it the input fields. i have used the NgModel